# dynamic height for image and cell in uitableview autoresizing

Tags: ios, uitableview, dynamic, height, autoresize

How to `set` the `dynamic height` for `image` and `cell` in `UITableView Autoresizing`. I have used auto resizing for `UI` in `Storyboard`. And I'm getting image with static width and dynamic height of image like Facebook from web service. Can anyone help me to set the dynamic height for both image and cell.

Comment: Now i'm using static height for both image and uitableviewcell. I need to set the dynamic height for image and uitableviewcell like facebook.

Comment: In story board give constraints to Imageview left,right,top, bottom corners and set your height in tableviewcell.It automatically works

Answer (score 1):

You can dynamically change height of tableviewcell using this method

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section{
 UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"yourImage"];
 return img.size.height;
}
```

Incase of you having imageurl after its get downloaded use below code to update height

```
UIImage *img=[UIImage imageWithData:data];
```

> [self.tableView beginUpdates];
>       [self.tableView endUpdates];

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement `UITableViewDelegate` and `UITableViewDataSource` method to do that and also you need to calculate the height of the cell in `heightForRowAtIndexPath` (`UITableViewDelegate` method) for each cell.

Comment: How to set the dynamic image height in uitableviewcell?

Comment: For that you need to calculate/get image height at runtime and return value from `heightForRowAtIndexPath` method.

Comment: How to calculate the image height at run time?

Answer (score 0):

You can provide dynamic height of UITableViewCell by using this method

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    return yourvalue;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)setDefaultRowHeights 
{
    self.imageHeights = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:self.imageURLs.count];
    for (int i = 0; i < self.imageURLs.count; i++) {
        self.imageHeights[i] = @(self.tableView.rowHeight);
    }
}
- (void)setDefaultRowHeights {
    self.imageHeights = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:self.imageURLs.count];
    for (int i = 0; i < self.imageURLs.count; i++) {
        self.imageHeights[i] = @(self.tableView.rowHeight);
    }
}
```

Then, let’s move on to tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath: where we’re downloading the images and storing their height in our imageHeights  array (this is a long one, but don’t freak out).

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    DynamicTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"DynamicCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    NSString *imageURL = self.imageURLs[indexPath.row];
    __weak DynamicTableViewCell *weakCell = cell;
    __weak typeof(self) weakSelf = self;
    [cell.mainImageView setImageWithURLRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:imageURL]]
                              placeholderImage:[UIImage new]
                                       success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, UIImage *image) {
                                           weakCell.mainImageView.image = image;
                                           // Update table row heights
                                           NSInteger oldHeight = [weakSelf.imageHeights[indexPath.row] integerValue];
                                           NSInteger newHeight = (int)image.size.height;
                                           // If image is wider than our imageView, calculate the max height possible
                                           if (image.size.width > CGRectGetWidth(weakCell.mainImageView.bounds)) {
                                               CGFloat ratio = image.size.height / image.size.width;
                                               newHeight = CGRectGetWidth(self.view.bounds) * ratio;
                                           }

                                           // Update table row height if image is in different size
                                           if (oldHeight != newHeight) {
                                               weakSelf.imageHeights[indexPath.row] = @(newHeight);
                                               [weakSelf.tableView beginUpdates];
                                               [weakSelf.tableView endUpdates];
                                           }
                                       } failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
                                           NSLog(@"Error: %@\nFetching image with url: %@", error, request.URL);
                                       }];

    return cell;
}
```

**Simple! We can now return proper values in the tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath: method like this:**

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return [self.imageHeights[indexPath.row] integerValue];
}
```

**Reloading table view cells properly**

Try experimenting with a few different approaches. I found that calling only beginUpdates  and endUpdates  produces the best animation/transition when cell height is changed. You could also put in the reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:  call between those two but it does an extra refresh and the UI looks crappy.

Comment: I have implemented this method. But my response may have both images and documents URL. I validated it but i coudn't get the exact index row of tableview for a image. Getting error in return [self.imageHeights[indexPath.row] integerValue].

Comment: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 7 beyond bounds [0 .. 5]'.

Comment: Your Array value Might be NIl.. so this error is appear in return [self.imageHeights[indexPath.row] integerValue].  check full code with Breakpoint..@MukeshN

Comment: if ([[[[dashboardList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"file"] valueForKey:@"type"] isEqualToString:@"image"]) {
[self.imageHeights[indexPath.row] integerValue]);
        return [self.imageHeights[indexPath.row] integerValue];
    }
    else {
        return 400;
    }

Comment: I found the problem. I'm having only 6 images in 10 rows in a tableview. Even though if i validate in heightForRowAtIndexPath from the above code. The problem is getting in the tableview indexpath.row.

Comment: ok..now you have to add 4 more image ELSE you have to use IF and ELSE conditon for Checking that if imageArray is null or not.   IF imagearray is null then Don't add image in Cell.

Comment: then why are you set 10 Row in tableview...set Imagearray.count in NumberOfRowinSection

Comment: can you show me your code..i will solve after show your code..right now i can't do anything without show your code.

Comment: if ([[[[dashboardList objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"file"] valueForKey:@"type"] isEqualToString:@"image"])
             {
              [self.imageURLs addObject:[[[dashboardList objectAtIndex:i]objectForKey:@"file"] valueForKey:@"low_res_url"]];
             }       I'm calling this from the response

Comment: - (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if ([[[[dashboardList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"file"] valueForKey:@"type"] isEqualToString:@"image"]) {
        return [self.imageHeights[indexPath.row] integerValue];
    }
    else {
        return 400;
    }
}